# How i can disable tag members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

sorry for the inconvenience, would someone be so kind to give me a hand to prevent people from tagging other members?

I don't have much experience so I would appreciate any help

```
client.on("message", message => {
if (message.content.includes("<@313496870305398784>")){
    message.channel.send("no tag this member");  
    };
});
```

Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You can't really _prevent_ that because you can't catch the message before it's sent to the channel. All you can do is delete the message and send "don't ping this user". But the member will be pinged anyway (ghost ping).

Comment: I understand, but how could I do what you say?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705824/7575111)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really *prevent* that because you can't catch the message before it's sent to the channel. 
All you can do is delete the message and send "don't ping this user". 
But the member will be pinged anyway (*ghost ping*).

In order to do that, check if the user's ID is in the [collection](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html) of mentioned users. 
Then, send your warning and delete the original message:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.mentions.has("313496870305398784")){
        message.channel.send("Don't ping this user.");
        message.delete();
    }
});
```